# Emulating Interfaces using Behaviours with Dialyzer in Erlang

Tags: java, interface, erlang, dialyzer

I want a Java interface equivalent in Erlang. How can I provide a `-spec` contract for the dialyzer that will allow me to get the as close as possible to functionality provided in Java?

Lets say I want something equivalent to this:

```
//Filename: Sports.java
public interface Sports
{
   public void setHomeTeam(String name);
   public void setVisitingTeam(String name);
}

//Filename: Football.java
public interface Football extends Sports
{
   public void homeTeamScored(int points);
   public void visitingTeamScored(int points);
   public void endOfQuarter(int quarter);
}

//Filename: Hockey.java
public interface Hockey extends Sports
{
   public void homeGoalScored();
   public void visitingGoalScored();
   public void endOfPeriod(int period);
   public void overtimePeriod(int ot);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement this with [`-callback`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/spec_proc.html#id73368) attributes:

```erlang
%% Filename: sport.erl
-module(sport).

-callback setHomeTeam(Name :: string()) -> ok.
-callback setVisitingTeam(Name :: string()) -> ok.
```

Then whenever you want to provide this interface:

```erlang
-behavior(sport).
```

I cannot however currently think of a way to do inheritance between behaviours. You can emulate it with included .hrl files that contain the relevant `-behaviour` attributes, instead of specifying them verbatim but this feels dirty.

Dialyzer will check that the callback satisfy the specified `-specs` if the behaviour modules are analyzed together with the modules that use them or are already in the PLT.